# Android Espresso keep app running after test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have the Espresso test and want to app stay on exact activity were test was finished. And i need to continue interaction with app.

```
@SmallTest
public void testOpenNavigationDrawer()
{
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(com.eleks.espresso.example.app.R.id.content_frame)).perform(ViewActions.swipeRight());
    ListView lvDrawerMenu = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(com.eleks.espresso.example.app.R.id.lvDrawerMenu);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(lvDrawerMenu, "lvDrawerMenu is null");
    final int count = lvDrawerMenu.getAdapter().getCount();
    Preconditions.checkPositionIndex(2, count, "No 1 index " + count + " size");
    Object obj = lvDrawerMenu.getItemAtPosition(2);
    Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.withId(com.eleks.espresso.example.app.R.id.tvItem), ViewMatchers.hasSibling(ViewMatchers.withText(obj.toString())))).perform(ViewActions.click());
}
```

How can i do that?
Thank you!

Comment: You could add the desired code in a `@Before` function. This way you will have the app in the screen you want before the tests are going to run.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the app running after a specific test so you can do certain manual interactions or even just to look at the end result longer. You can put a `Thread.sleep(MS);` at the end of your tests to make it sit there for however long you want.

To be fancy you can put another check after the sleep (and any interactions you do manually) and continue the tests. Obviously you don't want to do this very often as it does not make for good for auto testing.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use [Breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#breakPointsView) instead of `Thread.sleep()` if it's your case

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice against overwriting 'override fun finish(resultCode: Int, results: Bundle?) = Unit' in the test runner logic to prevent it from closing between tests, when using test suits.

It is messing up the Unit Test logic in 'Android Studio' and it had bad performance issues on the Android device.

However intercepting the activities to ignore all finish calls, does prevent the app from closing.

---

**Previous answer:**

What you want to achieve is easily possible.

To prevent your app from closing, you need to implement a custom instrumentation runner (e.g. create a class, that inherits from `androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`).

In this class you need to do the following things:

- overwrite the method `fun finish(resultCode: Int, results: Bundle?)` = empty body (the `super.finish` call is killing the app for good!)
- overwrite the method `fun useDefaultInterceptingActivityFactory()` = empty body
- overwrite the method `fun interceptActivityUsing(interceptingActivityFactory: InterceptingActivityFactory?)` = empty body
- overwrite the method `fun newActivity(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, intent: Intent): Activity`

  - if `intent.component?.packageName` is equal to your package, return custom activity classes, that either are your original activities or are custom test activities, which are inheriting from your activities

    - these returned activities need to overwrite the finish method and ignore this method call at certain times
    - In my tests I pass them a reference to a custom class implementing `InterceptedActivityHandler` interface, that provides various methods inspired by `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`, that allow me to selectively ignore / modify important calls in the activity class at test runtime
    - Once you did all that, you need to intercept the finish call of your currently open activity after your test has finished, that way your app can remain open between tests and when the full instrumentation test has finished
    - **Note:** Injection frameworks like dagger might give you a hard time, if you try to inject dependencies into an unknown activity class, which inherits from a known activity. I resolved this by annotating all intercepted activities with my custom annotation `InterceptedActivity`. Before injection I check, if the activity is annotated with `InterceptedActivity`. If that is the case, I reflectively create an instance of the super class, manually set the 'mContext' field to the application context, manually set the intent field to the intent of the child activity, inject into that created activity instance and then reflectivly copy all fields that are annotated with `javax.inject.Inject` from the parent instance to the child instance.
  - otherwise call `super.useDefaultInterceptingActivityFactory()` exactly once and return `super.newActivity(cl, classname, intent)`
- in your build.gradle(.kts)? file add `android.defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner = "some.package.path.MyCustomRunner"`

**MyCustomRunner**

```
class MyCustomRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    private data class InitApp(
            val cl: ClassLoader?,
            val className: String?,
            val context: Context?
    )

    private val atomicApp: AtomicReference<WeakReference<InitApp>?> = AtomicReference(null)
    private val app: Application by lazy(mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED) {
        val weak: WeakReference<InitApp> = this.atomicApp.get() ?: throw RuntimeException()
        return@lazy try {
            val initApp = weak.get() ?: throw RuntimeException()
            super.newApplication(initApp.cl, initApp.className, initApp.context)
        } finally {
            weak.clear()
        }
    }


    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        atomicApp.updateAndGet { old ->
            return@updateAndGet when (old) {
                null -> WeakReference(InitApp(cl = cl, className = className, context = context))
                else -> return@updateAndGet old
            }
        }
        return app
    }


    override fun finish(resultCode: Int, results: Bundle?) = Unit


    override fun useDefaultInterceptingActivityFactory() = Unit

    override fun interceptActivityUsing(interceptingActivityFactory: InterceptingActivityFactory?) = Unit

    override fun newActivity(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, intent: Intent): Activity {
        if(intent.component?.packageName == BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) {
             return super.newActivity(cl, className, intent)
        }

        return InterceptedSomeActivity(
             InterceptedPackageManager(app.packageManager),
             object : DefaultInterceptedActivityHandler(invokeMode = setOf(InvokeMode.LOG, InvokeMode.INVOKE_REAL)) {
                 override fun finish(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) {
                      val logClass: Class<*> = when (activity::class.java.getAnnotation(InterceptedActivity::class.java)?.logSuperClass) {
                          true -> activity::class.java.superclass
                          else -> activity::class.java
                      }
                      println("ignore finish for activity: ${logClass.name}")
                 }
             }
        )
    }
}
```

**InterceptedActivityHandler**

```
interface InterceptedActivityHandler /*: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity()*/ {
    /**
     * Called directly after instance construction
     */
    fun onInit(activity: Activity)

    fun onCreate(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) -> Unit, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    fun onStart(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit)
    fun onResume(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit)
    fun onPause(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit)
    fun onStop(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit)
    fun onDestroy(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit)

    fun setContentView(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (layoutResID: Int) -> Unit, layoutResID: Int)
    fun setContentView(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (view: View?) -> Unit, view: View?)
    fun setContentView(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (view: View?, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) -> Unit, view: View?, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?)
    var initDefaultActivityFactory: Boolean = false

    fun finish(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit)
}
```

**DefaultInterceptedActivityHandler**

```
open class DefaultInterceptedActivityHandler(
        private val invokeMode: Set<InvokeMode>
): InterceptedActivityHandler {
    override fun onInit(activity: Activity) = Unit

    override fun onCreate(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) -> Unit, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("onCreate", Bundle::class.java)) { invokeReal(savedInstanceState) }
    override fun onStart(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("onStart"), invokeReal = invokeReal)
    override fun onResume(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("onResume"), invokeReal = invokeReal)
    override fun onPause(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("onPause"), invokeReal = invokeReal)
    override fun onStop(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("onStop"), invokeReal = invokeReal)
    override fun onDestroy(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("onDestroy"), invokeReal = invokeReal)

    override fun setContentView(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (layoutResID: Int) -> Unit, layoutResID: Int) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("setContentView", Int::class.java)) { invokeReal(layoutResID) }
    override fun setContentView(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (view: View?) -> Unit, view: View?) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("setContentView", View::class.java)) { invokeReal(view) }
    override fun setContentView(activity: Activity, invokeReal: (view: View?, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) -> Unit, view: View?, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("setContentView", View::class.java, ViewGroup.LayoutParams::class.java)) { invokeReal(view, params) }

    override fun finish(activity: Activity, invokeReal: () -> Unit) = defaultMethodImpl(activity = activity, method = findActivityMethod("finish"), invokeReal = invokeReal)

    private fun defaultMethodImpl(activity: Activity, method: Method?, invokeReal: () -> Unit) {
        val superClassName: String = activity::class.java.superclass.name

        val identify = "${activity::class.java.name} ($superClassName): ${method?.let { method.parameters.joinToString(prefix = method.name + "(",separator = ", ", postfix = ")") { p -> "${p.name}: ${p.type.name}" } } ?: "<?>" })'"

        if(invokeMode.contains(InvokeMode.LOG)) {
            println("intercepted log: $identify")
        }

        when {
            invokeMode.contains(InvokeMode.THROW) -> throw NotImplementedError(identify)
            invokeMode.contains(InvokeMode.INVOKE_REAL) -> invokeReal()
        }
    }

    private fun findActivityMethod(name: String, vararg params: Class<*>): Method? = try {
        Activity::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(name, *params)
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        null
    }
}

enum class InvokeMode {
    INVOKE_REAL,
    THROW,
    LOG
}
```

**@InterceptedActivity**

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class InterceptedActivity(
        val logSuperClass: Boolean = true
)
```

**InterceptedSomeActivity**

```
@InterceptedActivity()
class InterceptedSomeActivity(
        private val packageManager: InterceptedPackageManager,
        private val interceptedActivityHandler: InterceptedActivityHandler
) : some.app.package.SomeActivity() {
    override fun getPackageManager(): PackageManager = packageManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = interceptedActivityHandler.onCreate(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { s -> super.onCreate(s) },
            savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState
    )

    override fun onStart() = interceptedActivityHandler.onStart(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { super.onStart() }
    )

    override fun onResume() = interceptedActivityHandler.onResume(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { super.onResume() }
    )

    override fun onPause() = interceptedActivityHandler.onPause(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { super.onPause() }
    )

    override fun onStop() = interceptedActivityHandler.onStop(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { super.onStop() }
    )

    override fun onDestroy() = interceptedActivityHandler.onDestroy(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { super.onDestroy() }
    )

    override fun setContentView(layoutResID: Int) = interceptedActivityHandler.setContentView(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { i: Int -> super.setContentView(i) },
            layoutResID = layoutResID
    )

    override fun setContentView(view: View?) = interceptedActivityHandler.setContentView(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { v: View? -> super.setContentView(v) },
            view = view
    )

    override fun setContentView(view: View?, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) = interceptedActivityHandler.setContentView(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { v: View?, p: ViewGroup.LayoutParams? -> super.setContentView(v, p) },
            view = view,
            params = params
    )

    override fun finish() = interceptedActivityHandler.finish(
            activity = this,
            invokeReal = { super.finish() }
    )
}
```

**InterceptedPackageManager**

```
class InterceptedPackageManager(
        private val actual: PackageManager
): PackageManager() {
    override fun getActivityInfo(component: ComponentName, flags: Int): ActivityInfo {
        if(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID != component.packageName) {
            return actual.getActivityInfo(component, flags)
        }

        val lookUpClazz: Class<*> = try {
            Class.forName(component.className, false, InterceptedPackageManager::class.java.classLoader)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            return actual.getActivityInfo(component, flags)
        }

        val annotation: InterceptedActivity? = lookUpClazz.getAnnotation(InterceptedActivity::class.java)
        if(Activity::class.java.isAssignableFrom(lookUpClazz) && annotation != null) {
            // use super class name for lookup
            return actual.getActivityInfo(ComponentName(debugAppPackageName, lookUpClazz.superclass.name), flags)
        }

        // use original implementation
        return actual.getActivityInfo(component, flags)
    }


    //<editor-fold desc="# pass to original package manager implementation #">
    override fun getPackageInfo(packageName: String, flags: Int): PackageInfo = actual.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags)
    override fun getPackageInfo(versionedPackage: VersionedPackage, flags: Int): PackageInfo = actual.getPackageInfo(versionedPackage, flags)
    override fun currentToCanonicalPackageNames(packageNames: Array<out String>): Array<String> = actual.currentToCanonicalPackageNames(packageNames)
    override fun canonicalToCurrentPackageNames(packageNames: Array<out String>): Array<String> = actual.canonicalToCurrentPackageNames(packageNames)
    override fun getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName: String): Intent? = actual.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
    override fun getLeanbackLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName: String): Intent? = actual.getLeanbackLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
    override fun getPackageGids(packageName: String): IntArray = actual.getPackageGids(packageName)
    override fun getPackageGids(packageName: String, flags: Int): IntArray = actual.getPackageGids(packageName)
    override fun getPackageUid(packageName: String, flags: Int): Int = actual.getPackageUid(packageName, flags)
    override fun getPermissionInfo(permName: String, flags: Int): PermissionInfo = actual.getPermissionInfo(permName, flags)
    override fun queryPermissionsByGroup(permissionGroup: String?, flags: Int): MutableList<PermissionInfo> = actual.queryPermissionsByGroup(permissionGroup, flags)
    override fun getPermissionGroupInfo(groupName: String, flags: Int): PermissionGroupInfo = actual.getPermissionGroupInfo(groupName, flags)
    override fun getAllPermissionGroups(flags: Int): MutableList<PermissionGroupInfo> = actual.getAllPermissionGroups(flags)
    override fun getApplicationInfo(packageName: String, flags: Int): ApplicationInfo = actual.getApplicationInfo(packageName, flags)
    override fun getReceiverInfo(component: ComponentName, flags: Int): ActivityInfo = actual.getReceiverInfo(component, flags)
    override fun getServiceInfo(component: ComponentName, flags: Int): ServiceInfo = actual.getServiceInfo(component, flags)
    override fun getProviderInfo(component: ComponentName, flags: Int): ProviderInfo = actual.getProviderInfo(component, flags)
    override fun getInstalledPackages(flags: Int): MutableList<PackageInfo> = actual.getInstalledPackages(flags)
    override fun getPackagesHoldingPermissions(permissions: Array<out String>, flags: Int): MutableList<PackageInfo> = actual.getPackagesHoldingPermissions(permissions, flags)
    override fun checkPermission(permName: String, packageName: String): Int = actual.checkPermission(permName, packageName)
    override fun isPermissionRevokedByPolicy(permName: String, packageName: String): Boolean = actual.isPermissionRevokedByPolicy(permName, packageName)
    override fun addPermission(info: PermissionInfo): Boolean = actual.addPermission(info)
    override fun addPermissionAsync(info: PermissionInfo): Boolean = actual.addPermissionAsync(info)
    override fun removePermission(permName: String) = actual.removePermission(permName)
    override fun checkSignatures(packageName1: String, packageName2: String): Int = actual.checkSignatures(packageName1, packageName2)
    override fun checkSignatures(uid1: Int, uid2: Int): Int = actual.checkSignatures(uid1, uid2)
    override fun getPackagesForUid(uid: Int): Array<String>? = actual.getPackagesForUid(uid)
    override fun getNameForUid(uid: Int): String? = actual.getNameForUid(uid)
    override fun getInstalledApplications(flags: Int): MutableList<ApplicationInfo> = actual.getInstalledApplications(flags)
    override fun isInstantApp(): Boolean = actual.isInstantApp
    override fun isInstantApp(packageName: String): Boolean = actual.isInstantApp(packageName)
    override fun getInstantAppCookieMaxBytes(): Int = actual.instantAppCookieMaxBytes
    override fun getInstantAppCookie(): ByteArray = actual.instantAppCookie
    override fun clearInstantAppCookie() = actual.clearInstantAppCookie()
    override fun updateInstantAppCookie(cookie: ByteArray?) = actual.updateInstantAppCookie(cookie)
    override fun getSystemSharedLibraryNames(): Array<String>? = actual.systemSharedLibraryNames
    override fun getSharedLibraries(flags: Int): MutableList<SharedLibraryInfo> = actual.getSharedLibraries(flags)
    override fun getChangedPackages(sequenceNumber: Int): ChangedPackages? = actual.getChangedPackages(sequenceNumber)
    override fun getSystemAvailableFeatures(): Array<FeatureInfo> = actual.systemAvailableFeatures
    override fun hasSystemFeature(featureName: String): Boolean = actual.hasSystemFeature(featureName)
    override fun hasSystemFeature(featureName: String, version: Int): Boolean = actual.hasSystemFeature(featureName, version)
    override fun resolveActivity(intent: Intent, flags: Int): ResolveInfo? = actual.resolveActivity(intent, flags)
    override fun queryIntentActivities(intent: Intent, flags: Int): MutableList<ResolveInfo> = actual.queryIntentActivities(intent, flags)
    override fun queryIntentActivityOptions(caller: ComponentName?, specifics: Array<out Intent>?, intent: Intent, flags: Int): MutableList<ResolveInfo> = actual.queryIntentActivityOptions(caller, specifics, intent, flags)
    override fun queryBroadcastReceivers(intent: Intent, flags: Int): MutableList<ResolveInfo> = actual.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, flags)
    override fun resolveService(intent: Intent, flags: Int): ResolveInfo? = actual.resolveService(intent, flags)
    override fun queryIntentServices(intent: Intent, flags: Int): MutableList<ResolveInfo> = actual.queryIntentServices(intent, flags)
    override fun queryIntentContentProviders(intent: Intent, flags: Int): MutableList<ResolveInfo> = actual.queryIntentContentProviders(intent, flags)
    override fun resolveContentProvider(authority: String, flags: Int): ProviderInfo? = actual.resolveContentProvider(authority, flags)
    override fun queryContentProviders(processName: String?, uid: Int, flags: Int): MutableList<ProviderInfo> = actual.queryContentProviders(processName, uid, flags)
    override fun getInstrumentationInfo(className: ComponentName, flags: Int): InstrumentationInfo = actual.getInstrumentationInfo(className, flags)
    override fun queryInstrumentation(targetPackage: String, flags: Int): MutableList<InstrumentationInfo> = actual.queryInstrumentation(targetPackage, flags)
    override fun getDrawable(packageName: String, resid: Int, appInfo: ApplicationInfo?): Drawable? = actual.getDrawable(packageName, resid, appInfo)
    override fun getActivityIcon(activityName: ComponentName): Drawable = actual.getActivityIcon(activityName)
    override fun getActivityIcon(intent: Intent): Drawable = actual.getActivityIcon(intent)
    override fun getActivityBanner(activityName: ComponentName): Drawable? = actual.getActivityBanner(activityName)
    override fun getActivityBanner(intent: Intent): Drawable? = actual.getActivityBanner(intent)
    override fun getDefaultActivityIcon(): Drawable = actual.defaultActivityIcon
    override fun getApplicationIcon(info: ApplicationInfo): Drawable = actual.getApplicationIcon(info)
    override fun getApplicationIcon(packageName: String): Drawable = actual.getApplicationIcon(packageName)
    override fun getApplicationBanner(info: ApplicationInfo): Drawable? = actual.getApplicationBanner(info)
    override fun getApplicationBanner(packageName: String): Drawable? = actual.getApplicationBanner(packageName)
    override fun getActivityLogo(activityName: ComponentName): Drawable? = actual.getActivityLogo(activityName)
    override fun getActivityLogo(intent: Intent): Drawable? = actual.getActivityLogo(intent)
    override fun getApplicationLogo(info: ApplicationInfo): Drawable? = actual.getApplicationLogo(info)
    override fun getApplicationLogo(packageName: String): Drawable? = actual.getApplicationLogo(packageName)
    override fun getUserBadgedIcon(drawable: Drawable, user: UserHandle): Drawable = actual.getUserBadgedIcon(drawable, user)
    override fun getUserBadgedDrawableForDensity(drawable: Drawable, user: UserHandle, badgeLocation: Rect?, badgeDensity: Int): Drawable = actual.getUserBadgedDrawableForDensity(drawable, user, badgeLocation, badgeDensity)
    override fun getUserBadgedLabel(label: CharSequence, user: UserHandle): CharSequence = actual.getUserBadgedLabel(label, user)
    override fun getText(packageName: String, resid: Int, appInfo: ApplicationInfo?): CharSequence? = actual.getText(packageName, resid, appInfo)
    override fun getXml(packageName: String, resid: Int, appInfo: ApplicationInfo?): XmlResourceParser? = actual.getXml(packageName, resid, appInfo)
    override fun getApplicationLabel(info: ApplicationInfo): CharSequence = actual.getApplicationLabel(info)
    override fun getResourcesForActivity(activityName: ComponentName): Resources = actual.getResourcesForActivity(activityName)
    override fun getResourcesForApplication(app: ApplicationInfo): Resources = actual.getResourcesForApplication(app)
    override fun getResourcesForApplication(packageName: String): Resources = actual.getResourcesForApplication(packageName)
    override fun verifyPendingInstall(id: Int, verificationCode: Int) = actual.verifyPendingInstall(id, verificationCode)
    override fun extendVerificationTimeout(id: Int, verificationCodeAtTimeout: Int, millisecondsToDelay: Long) = actual.extendVerificationTimeout(id, verificationCodeAtTimeout, millisecondsToDelay)
    override fun setInstallerPackageName(targetPackage: String, installerPackageName: String?) = actual.setInstallerPackageName(targetPackage, installerPackageName)
    override fun getInstallerPackageName(packageName: String): String? = actual.getInstallerPackageName(packageName)
    override fun addPackageToPreferred(packageName: String) = actual.addPackageToPreferred(packageName)
    override fun removePackageFromPreferred(packageName: String) = actual.removePackageFromPreferred(packageName)
    override fun getPreferredPackages(flags: Int): MutableList<PackageInfo> = actual.getPreferredPackages(flags)
    override fun addPreferredActivity(filter: IntentFilter, match: Int, set: Array<out ComponentName>?, activity: ComponentName) = actual.addPreferredActivity(filter, match, set, activity)
    override fun clearPackagePreferredActivities(packageName: String) = actual.clearPackagePreferredActivities(packageName)
    override fun getPreferredActivities(outFilters: MutableList<IntentFilter>, outActivities: MutableList<ComponentName>, packageName: String?): Int = actual.getPreferredActivities(outFilters, outActivities, packageName)
    override fun setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName: ComponentName, newState: Int, flags: Int) = actual.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, newState, flags)
    override fun getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName: ComponentName): Int = actual.getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName)
    override fun setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName: String, newState: Int, flags: Int) = actual.setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName, newState, flags)
    override fun getApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName: String): Int = actual.getApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName)
    override fun isSafeMode(): Boolean = actual.isSafeMode
    override fun setApplicationCategoryHint(packageName: String, categoryHint: Int) = actual.setApplicationCategoryHint(packageName, categoryHint)
    override fun getPackageInstaller(): PackageInstaller = actual.packageInstaller
    override fun canRequestPackageInstalls(): Boolean = actual.canRequestPackageInstalls()
    //</editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, but it's impossible.

I think you don't know enough good an idea of automated tests. \

Espresso, Robotium, Calabash and other UI test frameworks were made for short testing events. It simulates an user's specific behavior - run app, do some tricks and (if successful) than close an app.

Of course, Espresso allow you to create custom idling resources and than register it in app. Moreover, the simplest way to hibernate a test for a specific amount of time is use method `Thread.sleep(time_in_miliseconds)`, but like I said it's against idea of automated testing.

Comment: There is no wrong and right mate, it's just testing. You can do whatever suits your needs! There is a spirit and a way to do things, that may seem very polished and nice (like Hamcrest). But when you actually try to use it, you realise half of it is unfinished and garbage. So don't put other people down! He can expect to do a few automated tests and then expect the app to remain in this snapshot. Why not?